# Unable to keep the selection highlighted when i focus out of calendar in react full calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, react-fullstack

I'm using React Full Calendar.

I want to keep the selected date highlighted even when i click out of calendar i.e. maps here. I also want to highlight my custom event when clicked i.e. cropname. I'm attatching my jsx also.

Can someone help me with this?

[image: Frontend]

JSX=>

render() {
    return (

```
  <FullCalendar
    dafaultView="dayGridMonth"
    // defaultDate= '2017-12-12'
    eventLimit="true"
    eventLimitText="More"
    views={{
      month: {
        eventLimit: 3
      }
    }}
    dateClick={(e) => { this.onDateSelection(e) }}
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
    weekends={true}
    selectable="true"
    unselect={(e)=>e.jsEvent.preventDefault()}
    contentHeight="auto"
    showNonCurrentDates="false"
    events={this.state.calendarEvents && this.state.calendarEvents.list}
    // viewRender={(view, element) => { alert("render"); console.log(view, element) }}
    viewSkeletonRender={info => { this.addPaginationEvent(); }}
    eventRender={({ event, el }) => {
      const content = <div className="eventDetailContainer eventColor row justify-content-around">
        <div id="eventDetailImg"className="col-md-1" onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
          <img onClick={(e) => this.onCropSelect(event._def.extendedProps,e)} src={CropImageFinder(event._def.extendedProps.cropName)} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-5 harvestEventCropName harvestEventCropNameHideMobile">
          <span onClick={(e) => this.onCropSelect(event._def.extendedProps,e)} > {event._def.extendedProps.cropName} </span>
        </div>
        <div id="eventDetailQuantity"className="col-md-2 harvestEventCropName">
          <span onClick={(e) => this.onCropSelect(event._def.extendedProps,e)} > {event._def.extendedProps.cropQuantity + event._def.extendedProps.cropQuantityUnit } </span>
        </div>
      </div>;
      ReactDOM.render(content, el);
      return el;
    }
    }
  />
</section>)
```

}

Comment: i tried unselect, e.prevent default() is not even working there.

Comment: Could you please post your code as characters and not as an image.

Comment: Please [don't post images of your code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Code is **text**, please provide it as text. It should be less time to copy and paste than to create and upload a screenshot!

Comment: @ADyson I have attatched the code.It would be great if someone help me to find the solution.

Comment: Thanks. Ok. So, have you tried using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/unselectCancel? Or have you tried setting https://fullcalendar.io/docs/unselectAuto to false? Either one might be useful to you, depending on your specific requirements.

Comment: @ADyson I have tried all the possible attributes mentioned in fullcalendar but they are not working with React. p.s I have tried unselectCancel and unselectAuto as well

Comment: Well I don't know much about React, but it certainly works in standard fullCalendar. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JjodgEp . Select some dates on the calendar, and then click on the green area. The calendar selection will stay there. So I don't know what you did in React? Perhaps you should show us? Maybe the syntax is wrong or something, or maybe there's some other error. It's impossible to tell you, without seeing what you did. Maybe you can even make a running demo using an online sandbox? That would help a lot.